# How can I remove a datetime index values from a pandas data frame that are in between 6:00 p.m. and 9:00 a.m.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a data frame with a date time index that looks like this:

```
2020-11-10 11:20:00-5:00
...
2020-11-13 11:43:00-5:00
```

And I want to remove the entire row from every column that has a date time that is in between 6:00 p.m. and 9:00 a.m. for each day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `between_time` :

```
df.between_time('9:00', '18:00')
```